# How to shorten custom url using Bit.ly?

Tags: iphone, ios

I know how to shorten the urls using Bit.ly.I searched for how to shorten the custom urls(like tel://8004664411) using Bit.ly but I didn't find a way.can anyone provide me some information regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [bitly API Documentation](http://dev.bitly.com/get_started.html). There are docs on the request/response format of their service. You need to make a JSON request and get a response with the result. If you don't know how to do this, you can start with the [NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

//.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol BitlyShortUrlDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)BitlyShortUrlSucceededWithShortUrl:(NSString *)shortUrl;
- (void)BitlyShortUrlFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end

@interface BitlyShortUrl : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *data;
@property (unsafe_unretained) id<BitlyShortUrlDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)del;
- (void)bitlyUrl:(NSString *)longUrl;

@end
```

//.m

```
#import "BitlyShortUrl.h"

#define BITLY_LOGIN     @"YOUR_USERNAME"
#define BITLY_APIKEY    @"YOUR_APIKEY"
#define BITLY_URL       @"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?format=txt&longurl=%@&apikey=%@&login=%@"

@interface BitlyShortUrl ()

- (NSString *)encodeURL:(NSString *)url;

@end

@implementation BitlyShortUrl

@synthesize connection = _connection;
@synthesize data = _data;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)del {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        NSMutableData *mData = [NSMutableData new];
        [self setData:mData];
        [mData release];
        [self setDelegate:del];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)bitlyUrl:(NSString *)longUrl {
    if (nil == [self connection]) {
        NSString *encodedUrl = [self encodeURL:longUrl];
        NSString *endPoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:BITLY_URL, encodedUrl, BITLY_APIKEY, BITLY_LOGIN];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:endPoint]];

        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
}

- (NSString *)encodeURL:(NSString *)url {
    NSString * encoded = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                             NULL,
                                                                             (CFStringRef)url,
                                                                             NULL,
                                                                             (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                             kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [encoded autorelease];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self setConnection:nil];
    [self setData:nil];
    [self setDelegate:nil];

    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDelegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [[self data] appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if([self delegate] != nil && [[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(BitlyShortUrlSucceededWithShortUrl:)]) {
        NSString *shortUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self data] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [[self delegate] BitlyShortUrlSucceededWithShortUrl:[shortUrl autorelease]];
    }

    [self setConnection:nil];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if([self delegate] != nil && [[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(BitlyShortUrlFailedWithError:)]) {
        [[self delegate] BitlyShortUrlFailedWithError:error];
    }

    [self setConnection:nil];
}

#pragma mark -

@end
```

// Example ( implement delegate in your .h file )

```
BitlyShortUrl *yourUrl = [[BitlyShortUrl alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[yourUrl bitlyUrl:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Comment: Is it possible to shorten custom url like mailto://info@iphonedevelopertips.com using Bit.ly?

Answer (score 0):

This code converts any scheme

```
+ (NSString *)getTinyURL:(NSString *)url {
    NSString * encodedUrl = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                             NULL,
                                                                             (CFStringRef)url,
                                                                             NULL,
                                                                             (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                             kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    NSURL *tinyUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@", encodedUrl]];
    NSString *link = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:tinyUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
    return link;
}
```